# Get Version of App by NDK (no java layer)

Tags: android, c

how can I get the Version of my current running App by NDK?

I can get the name and the package, but I need the Version.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code,

```
int getVersionCode(JNIEnv *env, jobject context) {
    jstring packageName;
    jobject packageManagerObj;
    jobject packageInfoObj;
    jclass contextClass =  env->GetObjectClass( context);
         jmethodID getPackageNameMid = env->GetMethodID( contextClass, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
         jmethodID getPackageManager =  env->GetMethodID( contextClass, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");

    jclass packageManagerClass = env->FindClass("android/content/pm/PackageManager");
         jmethodID getPackageInfo = env->GetMethodID( packageManagerClass, "getPackageInfo", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");

    jclass packageInfoClass = env->FindClass("android/content/pm/PackageInfo");
         jfieldID versionCodeFid = env->GetFieldID( packageInfoClass, "versionCode", "I");

    packageName =  (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod( context, getPackageNameMid);

    packageManagerObj = env->CallObjectMethod(context, getPackageManager);

    packageInfoObj = env->CallObjectMethod( packageManagerObj,getPackageInfo, packageName, 0x0);
    int versionCode = env->GetIntField( packageInfoObj, versionCodeFid);

    return versionCode;
}
```

Comment: `int versionCode = (int)env->GetObjectField( packageInfoObj, versionCodeFid);` <-- Shouldn't that be `GetIntField` ?

Comment: thx for your answer.

But is there any way to get these information without usin the java layer? i want to get these information natively in c..

Comment: Currently there is no NDK API for getting version code directly, only through JNI, or you have to parse manifest xml manually and retrieve the info you need.

Comment: can you say me how can i parse manifest manually? i cannot find a way to do that...